# Emulador não carrega

Tags: android-studio, emulador

Estou precisando usar o IDE android studio, eu instalei ele todo certinho, só que na hora de rodar as aplicações feitas, o emulador só fica carregando, e não pega.

Configuração do meu Notbook:

Marca: Dell Inspiron 14'

Processador: Core i5

Mémoria Ram: 4GB

HD : 1TB

Log quando rodo o emualdor:

```
emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 2048MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1536MB.
emulator: device fd:1032
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1536 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 512 MB
emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
creating window 43 59 329 583
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check
                                                                    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

[image: Segue a imagem de como fica o emulador.]

Comment: Copia o log de erro por favor. Fotos são horriveis de compreender.

Comment: Clique naquela aba ali "Android Monitor" e cole o log de erro aqui...

Comment: Rodrigo edite a resposta, este campo é de comentários só.

Comment: já editei @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: O erro tá bem diferente da foto.

Comment: Editei o log @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Não há necessidade de traduzir o log. OBS: Por que o log da foto está diferente do que postou?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente você habilitou o emulador não suporta usar a câmera do hardware ou não haja câmera no hardware, isto se você selecionou a opção `Webcam0` por exemplo.

Faça o seguinte no *AVD manager*

1. No combo <kbd>Front Camera</kbd> e <kbd>back camera</kbd> selecione `None` ou `Emulated` em ambas.
2. Desmarque o <kbd>Snapshot</kbd> se estiver habilitado
3. Reinicie o emulador (se estiver travado faça logoff do seu usuário do sistema operacional)

Note que talvez se selecionar `Webcam0` nas duas opções, <kbd>Front Camera</kbd> e <kbd>back camera</kbd> pode conflitar também e falhar.

Comment: Vou verificar isso

Comment: é pra ir no AVD Manager ? não achei  ADV Maneger @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @RodrigoJacinto erro de digitação...

Comment: Coloquei a camera para Emulated, Emulated, e não resolveu  ela já tava None por Padrão. @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @RodrigoJacinto o log que você colou tem nada haver com o do foto, isso me fez fazer uma resposta errada e é por este motivo que colar o log na pergunta é tão importante, fora que você não postou o log todo provavelmente. Agora vou ter que apagar a resposta e tentar fazer uma nova infelizmente. Vou tentar aqui ver se descubro como resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Os computadores DELL e HP em alguns casos precisam ter o seu serviço de virtualização ativados para funcionar o emulador do android studio, segue o procedimento :

- Habilitando a virtualização em computadores Dell
- Pressione a tecla F12 quando o texto do menu de inicialização aparecer
- Selecione a opção inicialização de BIOS e pressione a tecla Enter
- Expanda o item do menu de Suporte de virtualização clicando no sinal de adição à 
  esquerda de Suporte de Virtualização e selecione a opção Virtualização
- Verifique a caixa de seleção Habilitar tecnologia de virtualização Intel
- Clique em Aplicar
- Clique em Sair
- Desligue totalmente o computador, espere alguns segundos e religue-o.

Comment: O erro parece com a cam e não com a virtualização. Mas vai saber

Comment: Vou tentar esse processo