# evento onclik() Erro ao abrir a camera

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação android que tenho um evento no Button para abrir a camera:

No AndroiManifest.xml

```
    <!-- Permissão para acessar a área de memória externa -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <!-- Permissão para acessar a câmera diretamente -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

No MainActivit tenho um ImageView e um ImageButton

```
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgv_imagem"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibtn_tirarfoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:onClick="takePicture"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
```

Na Activity.java tenho o método que acionado no evento onclick do Button

```
public void takePicture(View v) {
        // Cria uma intent que será usada para abrir a aplicação nativa de câmera
        Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        // Indica na intent o local onde a foto tirada deve ser armazenada
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));

        // Abre a aplicação de câmera
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_PICTURE);
    }
```

A chamado do método startActivityForResult está abrindo um IllegalStateException e dá a seguinte mensagem "Could not execute method for android:onClick"

O app é ecerrado após isso.
Aplico o mesmo código em uma outra aplicação e funciona.
Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Log de Erro:

```
11-18 16:41:02.205 30551-30551/br.com.multiwaycursos.multiwayapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: br.com.multiwaycursos.multiwayapp, PID: 30551
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
   at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716) 
   at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera } from ProcessRecord{c668b6b 30551:br.com.multiwaycursos.multiwayapp/u0a138} (pid=30551, uid=10138) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3181)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1541)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4298)
   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:54)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4245)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:708)
   at br.com.multiwaycursos.multiwayapp.actAutoCadastroCamera.TirarFoto(actAutoCadastroCamera.java:52)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716) 
   at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10926) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Estou usando um Navigation Drawer neste actvity, tentei em outra aplicação que usa o Navigation Drawer e deu o mesmo erro. A Classe MainActivity do Navigation Drawer herda da classe AppCompatActivity, diferente das outras que herdam da classe Activity

Comment: Qual é o `targetSdkVersion` e a versão do Android do dispositivo onde está a testar?

Comment: Olá ramaral, eu uso o targetSdkVersion 26, na API 21. O projeto está no endereço https://github.com/faelchristofano/MultiWayApp

Comment: Isso pode ser problema de [permissões em tempo de execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120879/2541) ou devido às [alterações das permissões com impacto na partilha de arquivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187127/2541). Coloque o log de erros completo.

Comment: Coloquei o log de erro

Answer (score 0):

Só olhar a primeira `Exception` (geralmente tem o texto `Caused by`), no seu log veja que contém o erro:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial ... with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA

Completo:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.sec.android.app.camera/.Camera } from ProcessRecord{c668b6b 30551:br.com.multiwaycursos.multiwayapp/u0a138} (pid=30551, uid=10138) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA

Parece que no Android 6.0 o sistema de permissões mudou:

> https://developers.google.com/android/guides/permissions#prerequisites
>
> Juntamente com as novas funcionalidades da plataforma, o Android 6.0 Marshmallow possui um novo modelo de permissões que simplifica o processo de instalação e atualização automática do aplicativo. As permissões agora são solicitadas em tempo de execução em vez de antes da instalação do aplicativo. Além disso, os usuários podem optar por negar permissões específicas.

Um exemplo para requisitar as permissões necessárias:

```
int permissionCheckStorage = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

if (permissionCheckStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    }, REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
}
```

<s>Provavelmente falta:</s>

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true" />
```

Também confira se o emulador (se estiver usando) esta com a câmera habilitada como expliquei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/167398/3635

### Extra

Uma sugestão que faço é checar o "pacote":

```
public void takePicture(View v) {
    // Cria uma intent que será usada para abrir a aplicação nativa de câmera
    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // Certifique-se de que haja uma atividade de câmera para lidar com o Intent
    if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

        // Indica na intent o local onde a foto tirada deve ser armazenada
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));

        // Abre a aplicação de câmera
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_PICTURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, fiz o que me pediu, mas o erro continua.
Coloquei as 2 permissões e alterei o método takePicture.
Eu estou usando meu celular Samsung J5 para executar. O estranho que o código funciona em outras activity, mas nessa não quer funcionar.

Comment: @RafaelChristófano tenta adicionar `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="true" />`, não estou bem certo se vai funcionar

Comment: Também não deu certo...

Comment: @RafaelChristófano creio que você talvez tenha desabilitado nas configurações, ou talvez você esteja usando o 23+. Vou editar a resposta

Comment: @RafaelChristófano editei, veja se consegue usar/aplicar.

Comment: em qual classe/método eu faço as requisições das permissões?

Comment: @RafaelChristófano antes de chamar o `Intent`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68942/discussion-between-rafael-christofano-and-guilherme-nascimento).